# When should I scale Bitmaps in my game

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I've just started developing my first game with Android using `SurfaceView`.

I scale my `Bitmap`s to support different screen sizes. But I don't know if it's better to do the scaling when loading the bitmaps or when drawing them to `Canvas` using Matrix.

I guess the first one would occupy more memory but it's better in performance. But I don't know how really things work here so any suggestion from experts would be appreciated.

Comment: if you want to scale them in loading bitmaps to reduce memory consumption you could use sprite sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to not scale the Bitmaps at all.  You can just scale the SurfaceView's surface instead.

See the "hardware scaler exerciser" in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) for an example, and [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html) for an explanation.  The basic idea is to call something like `surfaceView.getHolder().setFixedSize(1280, 720)` to set the surface's size to 1280x720, and then always render as if the display were 720p.  The hardware will scale it to whatever the current screen dimensions are.

It's slightly more complicated than that -- you want to pick a size that matches the display aspect ratio so your stuff doesn't look stretched (which is something you have to deal with on Android anyway).  Grafika does this to ensure that the square remains square.

This approach is *much* more efficient in both CPU and memory consumption than scaling individual bitmaps.